# How long can I store a 'naked' Pavlova?

Tags: storage-lifetime, storage, meringue

I've recently explored many Pavlova recipes and some of them say its ok to store the pavlova 3-4 day, while others say that one day of storage is already too much. As I've never made a Pavlova, I am asking myself:

How long can I store a Pavlova (without topping, but with nuts in it) in an airtight container before it's texture & flavor change so much that it won't be fun to eat?

Actually, I have stored baked meringues for 2 weeks in the past and they still were fine, but as a Pavlova is supposed to be gooey in the center, I can't imagine how long it will be good.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, storing pavlova in an airtight container makes it weep and go soft. My mother's tip is to keep it in the oven (a cool, turned off oven), as it's not air tight but it is 'out of the air'. It's always worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I made Pavlovas 2 weeks ago for a wedding, 2 were left over. They are sitting on parchment paper and wrapped 3 times in cling film and have been in the fridge since then. I am having guests on Sunday 7th June and am going to put cream and fresh fruit on them. I have just checked them and they are fine.

Answer (score 1):

They are sold in boxes in grocery stores so they must be good for at least a week or more. Should not be stored in plastic containers, wrap a few times in plastic wrap loosely and store in fridge. They only weep in my experience if they are not cooked properly and left to dry out over night in the oven. Do not open oven door when cooking, when finished cooking turn off oven and slow to cool over night without ever opening the oven door. The inside is marshmallow so they should keep well.

Comment: Sharon, welcome! As for all new users I recommend you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the SE system in general. You'll even get a nice badge for doing so ;-) . We are here if you need more support.

Comment: While I assume you are right with your time estimate, I'd hesitate using store-bought products as reference: they are usually made and packed in a commercial setting and, depending on where you are, might contain preservatives a standard household recipe can't or wouldn't use.

Comment: Also bought pavlovas tend to be made crisp all the way through, which stops them weeping.

Answer (score 0):

A tip for a good strong pavlova that wont sink or weep is to mix 2 teaspoons of cornflour with a table spoon of white vinegar and add this to your egg whites while you are mixing them and this also helps to preserve your pavlova wrapped in cling wrap for a couple of days in the fridge before you top with what ever you are using

Comment: Why would this help? I can understand the corn flour, but not the vinegar.

Answer (score 0):

I've done pavs before and in our extreme heat, I leave the pav outside in the warm air and then just a 1/2 hour in the oven on 120 degrees is enough to make it crispy and soft marshmellow in the centre. Does not weep. Store in a loose wrap of plastic for a couple of days or even a bag.  Awesome.